Parial Derivative of a kronecker product
Let's say we have a function $f(x, A, B) = (A \otimes B)x$. We can assume A and B are matrices and x is some input matrix (it can be a vector).
And I need to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$.
I know that $\partial f = (\partial A \otimes B)x + (A \otimes \partial B)x + (A \otimes B) \partial x$ Matrix Cookbook, Pg 8
Can I write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} = (I \otimes B)x$?
And similarly $\frac{\partial f}{\partial B} = (A \otimes I)x$?

Can you state in the question in which spaces $x, A, B$ leave?

I have updated the question.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}(x,A,B)$ is the linear map $L$ such that $L(H)=(H\otimes B)x$. I doubt you can make sense of $(I\otimes B)x$ as a coordinate representation of $L$, but Kronecker product has never really been my cup of tea. More of the same for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}$

Thanks! And what kind of input data do you have? To understand what means $(A \otimes B)x$.

It can be a matrix, but for simplicity, you can assume it to be a vector.

Write out explicitly $(A\otimes B)x$ for a low dimensional example. The calculation of the partial derivatives is then straightforward.

What is for sure, is that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} (x,A,B) \cdot h = (h \otimes B)x$. The question then, as Sassatelli Giulio mentioned is how would you apply $(I \otimes B)x$ to $h$? Remember that by definition $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ is a linear map from the space where $A$ is to the one of $(A \otimes B)x$.

I have made some more edits to my question.

@SatyaPrakashDash What meaning would you give to the writing you suggest?

@SatyaPrakashDash What is unclear in this context is what exactly the expected data type is for something like $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$. The derivatives that can be "naturally" represented in the form of a matrix are scalar-by-matrix, vector-by-vector, and matrix-by-scalar. See this Wikipedia page for a more thorough discussion. The computation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ is a vector-by-matrix derivative (or a matrix-by-matrix derviative if you allow for $x$ to be a matrix)

@SatyaPrakashDash The "natural" representation of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ would be a third-order tensor (i.e. as a 3-dimensional array) rather than as a matrix (a 2-dimensional array), so there is no standard way to express $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ as a matrix. If there is some convention that you would like to follow for making sense of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ as a matrix, then it is up to you to spell that out.

@BenGrossmann, I am just asking here. I though the math results in tensors only, which I got here. Btw do you have a reference for the 3-tensor you saying?

@SatyaPrakashDash One alternative to getting an expression for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ (which also works in the case where $x$ is a matrix) would be to get an expression for $\frac{\partial g_M}{\partial A}$, where $M$ is a matrix whose shape is the same as $f(x,A,B)$ and $g_M(x,A,B) = \operatorname{tr}[M^T f(x,A,B)]$. Note that the derivative of a specific entry of $f(x,A,B)$ with respect to $A$ could be obtained by taking $M$ to be a standard basis element, i.e. a vector or matrix with one entry equal to $1$ and the other entries equal to $0$.

@SatyaPrakashDash Since you are referring to $\otimes$ as a "Kronecker product", $A \otimes B$ is a matrix rather than a fourth-order tensor. Consequently, $(I \otimes B)x$ is a vector if $x$ is a vector or a matrix if $x$ is a matrix, which is the wrong data type. Note that if $\otimes$ is interpreted as a tensor product, then there is no standard interpretation for the expression $(A \otimes B)x$.

See Page 60: point 520 of https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf which says how to convert a vec kronecker product to matrix multiplication. So I don't get what is wrong with this?

@SatyaPrakashDash I don't understand what concern you think that you are addressing by telling me how the vec operator works. Take a look at the reference that you're pointing me to. Among the many formulas for derivatives for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ where $A$ is a matrix that they give, do they give even one such formula where the function $f$ produces a vector or a matrix?

@SatyaPrakashDash Again, to summarize: for a matrix $A$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ only makes sense (in the same way that these derivatives are interpreted in the matrix cookbook) if $f$ produces a scalar output, which your function $f$ does not.

@SatyaPrakashDash Another workaround that you might consider is to use the vec operator to regard $A$ as a vector, so that the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \text{vec}(A)}$ is a vector-vector derivative and hence computable as a matrix.

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\k{\otimes}  \def\h{\odot}  \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Aij{A_{ij}}
\def\Eij{E_{ij}}
$The component-wise self-gradient of a matrix is
$$\eqalign{
\grad A{\Aij} &= \Eij \\
}$$
where $\Eij$ is the single-entry matrix (which is also in the cookbook) whose elements are all zero except for the $(i,j)$ element which equals one.
If $A\in\R{m\times n},\:$ these single-entry matrices are the standard basis for $\R{m\times n}$
Similarly, for $f\in\R{p}$ the single-entry vectors
$\,e_k=\large{\grad{f}{f_k}}\,$ are the standard basis for $\R p$

Applying this to the Matrix Cookbook formula
$\LR{{\rm and\ holding}\ \{B,x\}\ {\rm constant}}$ yields
$$\eqalign{
df &= \LR{\c{dA}\k B}x \qiq
\grad f\Aij &= \LR{\c{\Eij}\k B}x \\
}$$
To recover the full gradient (a third-order tensor),
extract the $k^{th}$ component of the previous result
$$\eqalign{
{\large\Gamma}_{kij}
 \;=\; \grad{f_k}\Aij
 \;=\; e_k^T\LR{\c{\Eij}\k B}x \\
}$$

Thanks for the simplified explanation. Do you have any resources to follow up regarding calculus with the Kronecker product? Thanks.

The classic book Kronecker Products and Matrix Calculus with Application by Alexander Graham was recently re-published by Dover so it's very affordable.
